# Getting sql exception and wants to know how write this query properly?

Tags: mysql

i am getting SQL exception for this query because of wrong syntax and wants to know how to write this query?

i am using MySQL 5 and spring in Java to use this query.

```
SELECT
  MAX
  (
      nivpof_buystock.price*
      (
        SELECT
          no_of_shrs
        FROM nivpof_sellstock
        WHERE p_id=sellpid
          AND AUDIT_DATE_TIME=udate
      )
  )
  INTO acquisition_cost
FROM nivpof_buystock,nivpof_sellstock
WHERE nivpof_buystock.P_ID=sellpid
  ;
  IF
  (
      (
          (
            SELECT
              MAX(DATE)
            FROM nivpof_buystock
            WHERE (sc_code=company_code AND STATUS='Y' AND user_id=userid)
          )
          <'2018-01-31'
      )
      AND
      (
        SELECT
          DATEDIFF
          (
              (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM nivpof_sellstock WHERE (sc_code=company_code AND STATUS='Y' AND user_id=userid)),
              (
                SELECT
                  MAX(DATE)
                FROM nivpof_buystock
                WHERE (sc_code=company_code AND STATUS='Y' AND user_id=userid)
              )
          )
          >365
      )
  )
  THEN
SELECT
  MAX
  (
    SELECT
      CLOSE_PRICE
    FROM niv_companystockdetails
    WHERE
      (
          sc_code=company_code
          AND DATE='2018-01-31'
      )
      *
      (
        SELECT
          no_of_shrs
        FROM nivpof_sellstock
        WHERE p_id=sellpid
          AND AUDIT_DATE_TIME=udate
      )
  )
  INTO acquisition_cost
FROM nivpof_buystock,nivpof_sellstock
WHERE nivpof_buystock.P_ID=sellpid
ENDIF;
```

for example buyprice=5,buydate=2017-01-24,selldate=2018-02-25, closeprice of 2018-01-31=10.

so here i want to check if (buydate<2018-01-24 AND selldate-buydate>365days AND closepriceof 2018-01-31>buyprice) then
buyprice= closepriceof 2018-01-31;

Comment: Please edit your code to make it readable.

Comment: Also post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Typically java runs one SQL statement at at time, and not multiple ones (with the notable exception of batches).

If you look at your query, you are trying to run multiple sentences (do you see those `;` there?) while also trying to add some insertion logic to it (`IF` / `ENDIF`).

I suggest you run each SQL statement separately. That should solve the problem.